# How do I make it so you cant type until the input prompts you?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm making a text game and I'm using the `time.sleep` delay. When I try it, it allows me to type during the time delay, before it asks you to input. Is there any way to fix this?

```
print ("The first member is a miner.")
time.sleep(1)
miner = input ("What is his name?  ")
```

Comment: Do you want it to sleep before ``"What is his name?"`` or after? Either way, try adding ``sys.stdout.flush()`` before your sleep. My guess is that it actually is sleeping, it just hadn't printed out the ``"The first member is a miner"`` yet, and ``flush`` will force that.

Comment: @eryksun Ah right python 3 :p

Comment: @aruisdante Nope, didn't work; I just checked. I don't actually think that restricting typing in the IDLE is possible, after a quick Google search.